# legacy dojo 1.1 - dojo.addOnLoad fires when dijit stuff is not ready

Tags: dojo, legacy, dijit.form

I'm forced to use dojo 1.1 on a site.

The page uses dijit widgets in declarative way, as in:

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect">...</select>
```

I want to do some stuff on widgets after load, but if I do:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  dijit.registry.forEach(function(widget, idx, hash) {
    alert('Hello! I am a widget!');
  });
});
```

no alerts appear, as this code is execuded *before* the "dijitification" of the page, as I found out while debugging.

Is there a way to execute my code when the page is really, really ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case I (or anyone else) need it again, this is how I solved this:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  dojo._loaders.push(someFunction);
});
```

This seems to ensure that `someFunction` is executed after *all* other callbacks, included dijit callbacks.