# elastic textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<form action="" method="">
<input name="title" type="text" maxlength="256" value="daniel"/>
<input name="description" type="text" maxlength="512" value="awesome"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function resize(elem){
if(!elem.value.length) elem.size=1;
else elem.size=elem.value.length;
}


var elem=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i in elem){
elem[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(){resize(this);}, false);
resize(elem[i]);
}
```

CSS:

```
input{
display:block;
font-size:12px;
}
```

all of this is working, but i am not quite satisfied. as you can see actual text representation is quite smaller than text field boundaries. this is pronounced as text gets longer. is there any css trick to minimize this offset?

you can check example page [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zUBar/)

many thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's all working. Try holding down a letter. Or, try putting in `w` lots of times (pressing and releasing the letter each time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ubch/

The `size` attribute is unfortunately rather imprecise; it makes more sense to set the width of the element via the `style` property.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ubch/1/) of a method that uses a hidden `pre` element with the same font as the input element to provide a more accurate width. I've used the `keydown` event as well as `keyup` because the former fires on each key repeat. Using a `pre` element means that multiple space characters are not collapsed.

(Of course, I dove straight into the code, but I just thought to search and [someone wrote a simple jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288297/jquery-auto-size-text-input-not-textarea) that does the same job as this. I've stuck to plain old DOM methods, but it might be useful if you go down that route in the future.)

Comment: Hmm, actually, I like TJ's method of using setTimeout, which gets around the problem of e.g. deleting the whole field. I think he gets the cookie this time! 

If you don't want to use jQuery, the `offsetWidth` property is fairly well supported, and I suggest you try my approach of using a `pre` element instead of a `span`. (Remember to add `display: inline;` to the resizer element CSS if you do.)

Comment: that is one very nice example. many thanks, it improved my view on possible code structure too. i haven't known that you can write code like that: var something={label: value, ...} if you could also refer me to documentation that covers this in more details would be awesome. many thanks

Comment: [i have found it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). i was not aware of object initializer's existence

Comment: Glad you found it! I'm using it as a very rough-and-ready sort of namespacing, since `test` is quite a generic name for a function and there could be a collision; however, you might also want to check out [playing nice with anonymous functions](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2006/11/22/play-nice-with-others-javascript-namespace/), which libraries like jQuery use to "hide" their code. The notation I just used is susceptible to [issues to do with scope](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations/) that will cause you all manner of pain and heartache in due course!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a proportional font, the size of the field is always only going to be approximately correct when given in fixed units like the `size` attribute (or CSS's `em` units). You could mitigate this by making the font of the `input` monospaced, but that's obviously got some downsides.

The only solution I'm aware of for doing this to a high level of quality involves an off-screen element (a `span` is good) that's allowed to grow automatically, and then mapping the size of that div onto the size of the element.

---

**Update**: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zUBar/5/ Apologies, I don't do computed widths manually, so I've added jQuery into the mix for the purposes of the example. If you don't use jQuery, you should be able to use the features of the library you do use (or `getComputedStyle` or similar) to get the same information, which is the resulting width of the off-screen span. Things of note:

- You need to give the browser a moment to resize the `span`, hence the `setTimeout`
- The `span` is off to the far left of the page, which prevents scrollbars from appearing unnecessarily
- I've explicitly set the same font for the `input` and the `span`