# How to increase width of textfield according to typed text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to increase the width of input text field automatically if a user inputs some text in it. But how to do it. Please help me.Can it be using Jquery or javascript

Thanks.

Comment: this is duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288297/jquery-auto-size-text-input-not-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<script>
function adjustWidth(obj) {

    obj.style.width = (obj.value.length) * 7.3 + "px";
}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="adjustWidth(this)">
```

However this depends on text size, font, etc

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EaXpV/)

```html
<input style="width:100px" onkeyup="var len = this.value.length; 
    if (len>10) {
      this.style.width=(parseInt(this.style.width)+10)+'px';
    }" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The width cannot be increased as precisely as the width of character vary from one another.

But still, you can do something like this

```
$("input:text").keyup(function() {
    $(this).css('width', $(this).val().length*10);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/gBxGZ/)
As you can see I am assuming that for every character the field size has to be increased by 10px. This is very hard to assign a correct ration that fits all the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it precisely. You do this by opening an absolutely-positioned div off-screen with the same font as your textbox and populating it with the text of your textbox on keyup. You then take the width of that div (which will conform to the text) and set your textbox to that width.

Note that the div needs to be off-screen (left:-9999px), not hidden (display:none) or it won't work since the browser needs to render the text in order to calculate the width. Also, setting the text of the div to your textbox contents plus a trailing space will help ensure that your textbox is always one character larger than needed, accounting for any lag between the key being displayed and the width being updated.

After the break I'll post a modified version of James Padolsey's [JQuery Autoresize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) script that works with textareas to first resize the width to some maximum size, then the height once the text wraps. It's not exactly what you are looking for, but it might help.