# jQuery clip an input field to the contents of that input

Tags: jquery, user-interface, input, resize

I am currently re-sizing my input text boxes to match the content that is typed into them with the following code:

```
var lenStr = $(this).val().length;
 var boxWidth = lenStr * 8.55;

 $(this).css({width:boxWidth});
```

However the calculation is flawed as the more characters in the value the greater the gap of white space at the end of the input field: -

http://jsfiddle.net/kLKNk/

I would like to clip my input fields so that there is no gap or large amount of white space at the end. I have seen a jQuery fn on here that resizes boxes but adds a comfort amount to the end, can anyone think of a better equation I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - auto size text input (not textarea!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288297/jquery-auto-size-text-input-not-textarea)

Comment: No... it's not a duplicate I am asking how to re-size the content of the input field to the same width as the text entered by the user. I am already resizing but have an imperfect method or equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way i've found so far is to use a monospaced font and manually set the letter spacing in the CSS to 0px. Another popular method seems to be to create a hidden or displaced element with the contained text, get the width of that element and set the box accordingly.