# change textarea height depend on text on DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

When the DOM is loaded, i want to check all my textareas and change their height depending on the text contained.
It should look something like that:

```
 $().ready(function (){
     //my check textares code
 });
```

Can anyone give me advice how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like to me you haven't made an attempt and are looking for someone to give you the answer, in which case you have come to the wrong place. Come back when you actually have a specific question and some workings of your own.

Comment: What code do you already have, did you try searching for something like: "auto adjust size textarea". http://bit.ly/IDgBS5

Comment: Ofc i tried, there are a lot of plugins, which do that on fly, when text typing by user, but i don`t wont to use plugins, think that can be done in some easy way.

Comment: Have you looked at how those plugins work?  Figure out what methods make those plugins work and you'll know how to implement it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288297/jquery-auto-size-text-input-not-textarea

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Answer (score 0):

Since you use jquery, you might as well use [plugin jgrow](https://github.com/berkerpeksag/jGrow/tree/master/src) for that

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery plugin Autosize.

you can download this:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

just declare like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();  
});
```