# How to expand inputs to fit properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

First image is the current one, and the second one is what I'm trying to get. However nothing seems to be working, can anyone help me with this?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>speaker</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="block container" id="container">
                        <center><img src="img/logo.png"></img></center>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        Name: <input class="block" id="name" type="text">
                        Post: <input class="block" id="post" type="text">
                        <a class="block" href="#" id="submit">Submit!</a>
                        <div class="separator"></div>
                        Followed tags:<input class="block" id="post" type="text"><br>
                        <span class="author">Separate tags with spaces, like; #tomatoes #cats #music
                        <div id="postbreak"></div>
                </div>

                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself

Comment: try using tables for your forms...

Comment: Does the form need to be responsive (fluid)? Also, there doesn't seem to be an actual form tag in the code?

Comment: As Josh KG hinted at, if the form doesn't have to be fluid you could just set explicit widths on your individual input fields.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288297/jquery-auto-size-text-input-not-textarea this will help u

Comment: y cant you give percentage?

Comment: @redDevil Don't go there.

Comment: Why is this being closed :s

Answer (score 0):

hey you can give a inline styling and change the width of the input box

```
 Name: <input class="block" id="name" type="text" style="width:150px;">
                    Post: <input class="block" id="post" type="text" style="width:280px;">
                    <a class="block" href="#" id="submit">Submit!</a>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                    Followed tags:<input class="block" id="post" type="text" style="width:480px;"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is:

To take percentage of each input from the whole area.
 Here is how:
[image]

Comment: Percentages would work but you'd also have to take into account the labels for Name and Post as well as the Submit input, float them all, or alternatively give them absolute positioning and appropriate `left` values.

Comment: Are you doing this as responsive?