# input[type=text] vertically grow the input after x characters and vertically align the text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Did a search and no joy... posting the question, if an existing answer exists, please share it :)

So what I have is a basic input field:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="bar" value="" maxlength="200" required>
```

What I would like to have happen, and I know this goes against all standards, but lets just ignore that, is to have the input field grow *vertically* (ie: downward) after the user has typed in a set number of characters (lets say, 30) so it looks more like a `type=[textarea]` than it does a `type=[text]`

It should also have the text stay aligned at the top of the input field and not be middle centered.

How would we go about doing this with `query` and `css` ??

Comment: Why don't you use `textarea`? This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1288297/3639582

Answer (score 0):

use textarea auto resize...download the jquery from [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) and add `$(textarea).autoResize();` to your code and if u want it in jquery and html refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/WM6Gq/189/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what  you are looking for:-
[image]

When I give height`(say height:300px;)` to `<input type="text">` tag, it shows text in middle, but to show text on the top, we have to give bottom padding`(say padding-bottom:300px;)`, then it'll keep text on the top and will look like a text area.

```
<style type="text/css">
input#bar{ padding-bottom:300px;}
</style>
<input type="text" name="foo" id="bar" value="" maxlength="200" required>
```