# Part of javascripts gets cut off in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2007

Greetings

One of my clients javascript files is failing. I have found the reason, but the discovery has made me REALLY confused as I have never seen anything like it.

The issue is that when the browser reads through the script sources and enters a specific custom .js file which contains 543 lines of code, it only reads to line 502 which is this `if (isValidWidthChange) {` but what confuses me is that when I use developer tool in IE and firebug in FireFox and uses their script debug tool, when it hits line 502, the javascript is cut off like so - `if (isValidWidthChan`

`if (isValidWidthChange) {`

`if (isValidWidthChan`

Can anyone give me a logic explanation on WHY this happens?

I can say so much that I was adding a few things to the file, but I took a back-up of the original before starting, and this is actually the error which keeps occuring even after I set the website to use the original file again.

I have tried IISRESET a lot of times. I have tried copying the file from a healthy environment. I have cleared all the caches in my browsers and on the server. Yet it still appears.

I didn't develop it myself, it's a third party product. But this has never happened before.

Codesnippet of where the error occurs

```
(function($) {
    // jQuery autoGrowInput plugin by James Padolsey
    // See related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields
    $.fn.autoGrowInput = function(o) {
        o = $.extend({
            maxWidth: 1000,
            minWidth: 0,
            comfortZone: 70
        }, o);
        this.filter('input:text').each(function() {
            var minWidth = o.minWidth || $(this).width(),
                val = '',
                input = $(this),
                testSubject = $('<tester/>').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: -9999,
                    left: -9999,
                    width: 'auto',
                    fontSize: input.css('fontSize'),
                    fontFamily: input.css('fontFamily'),
                    fontWeight: input.css('fontWeight'),
                    letterSpacing: input.css('letterSpacing'),
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
                }),
                check = function() {
                    if (val === (val = input.val())) { return; }
                    // Enter new content into testSubject
                    var escaped = val.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                    testSubject.html(escaped);
                    // Calculate new width + whether to change
                    var testerWidth = testSubject.width(),
                        newWidth = (testerWidth + o.comfortZone) >= minWidth ? testerWidth + o.comfortZone : minWidth,
                        currentWidth = input.width(),
                        isValidWidthChange = (newWidth < currentWidth && newWidth >= minWidth)
                                             || (newWidth > minWidth && newWidth < o.maxWidth);
                    // Animate width
                    if (isValidWidthChange) { // This is where it stops
                        input.width(newWidth);
                    }
                };
            testSubject.insertAfter(input);
            $(this).bind('keyup keydown blur update', check);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: are there any other scripts loading? are they ok?

Comment: Inspect your http responses (with firebug or httpfox). It is possible the server is (for some reason) not returning the whole script.

Comment: @Daniel It's in all of the browsers.
@ppumkin Yes there are other scripts loading and they work just fine.

Comment: Sounds like server or SharePoint issue. Try renaming the `.js` file and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably encoding issue, please make sure you don't have special characters in all the  script;

Look on the characters near Owns and Rate, that characters will be ignored by the browser and the script will be cut off by the amount of them

```
/*
    Mapping GUI to event types
    Click - clickEvents
    Purchase -purchaseEvents
    Consume - consumeEvents
    Recommended - clickedRecommended
    Rendered - renderedEvents
    Rate ײateEvents
    Blacklist - blacklistEvents
    Owns ׯwnsEvents
    Total

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to split the script into two parts? 543 lines is quite a lot of code, and I would be surprised if there are not at least some functions or modules which could be moved to a separate script.

As for debugging the issue, your symptoms would suggest that your server may have some kind of maximum content length. I know there are maximums (maxima?) for requests (there is something called `maxAllowedContentLength`, which is configurable), but I would be surprised if there was an upper limit on the size of files **served**. (Frankly that would be damn stupid, and would cause lots of problems but hey, IIS is not always smart - or maybe your administrator has been a bit too parsimonious?). It would be interesting to check if the maximum is a matter of lines or (more likely) bytes. So, to check this, have you tried:

- Adding comments - does this shift the
  break-off point?
- Adding additional
  (unused) code - does this shift the
  break-off point?
- Serving another long
  script, for example you could get a
  hold of the developer version of
  jQuery (rather than the minified
  one). Does this get broken-off too?

The results of these experiments and similar would help narrow down the issue a little.