# Contenteditable Height transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a contenteditable div which [grows as the user types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type).

I now need to transition the height so that when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the div would grow slowly.

Here's the animation I'm looking for (but when the user creates a new line rather than on focus):

[image]

And here's my (probably naive) attempt:

CSS:

```
div[contenteditable]{
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition : all 300ms ease;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable>
    Testing <br/> one two three
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gD5jy/124/)

Can I achieve this using only HTML/CSS or do I have to resort to JS?

Comment: The value of height is `auto` and it never changes in your example. Ergo there's no transition. Transitions from and to `auto` also wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok. So how do I make it work?

Comment: Not without JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, I've also tried but there doesn't seem to be any max-height trickery I can use to work my way out of this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
@keyframes lineInserted {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 20px; /* cons: hardcoded height */
  }
}
div[contenteditable] > div {
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-name: lineInserted;
  transition: height 300ms;
}
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  Testing
  <br/>one two three
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The animation seems to "bounce back" though http://gph.is/1h6i480 Also, any way I can make it transition when lines are removed?

Comment: Fixed "bounce back" problem with     `line-height : 20px;`

Comment: I'm not sure if you could still detect DOM removal through CSS. You might already need to use JS DOMNodeRemoved event there.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution based on Orland's answer. Thank you, bootstrap!

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div contenteditable class="form-control">
    Testing <br/> one two three
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes lineInserted {  
    from { height: 0; }
    to { height: 20px; }  /* cons: hardcoded height */
}

div[contenteditable] > div {
    animation-duration: 200ms;
    animation-name: lineInserted;
}

div[contenteditable]{
    height : auto !important;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height : 20px;
}
```

[image]