# Prevent everything other than newlines and plaintext in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

Coming from [Contenteditable Height transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839844/contenteditable-height-transition/32840600#32840600)

I've quickly realized that a contenteditable div can change from:

```
 <div contenteditable> </div>
```

To this:

```
<div contenteditable style="background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: repeat;"><b><i>
    Testing <br> one two three
</i></b><div><b><i><br></i></b></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div></div>
```

Is there an easy way to prevent the user from entering anything other than plaintext and newlines? I will clean it serverside, and can also do some preliminary cleaning through JavaScript, but giving the user the idea that they can make text bold, etc. in the first place is not very good.

Comment: So, you want that only `br` elements stay there? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Essentially I need it to behave like a textinput. I'm only using contenteditor so it can grow.

Comment: I think the downvotes say "just use a text input, dammit". Ok, got it guys.

Comment: You need to do it server side, never trust the client. And you can use the same cleaner front-side by listening to the [HTML5 input events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) and cleaning the actual content, or with the keyup/keydown events.

Comment: How do you post the content and what do you get serverside ?

Comment: Some browsers add wrap a `<br>` into a `<div>` when pressing *return* key. You could use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398548/2168947) as a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's none unless you would use a textarea.