# Contenteditable height transition: animate after adding (shift+enter) and removing a line of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It works so far on using the `contenteditable` attribute on the `<div>` tag [with the autogrow feature of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type). Also the [height transition of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839844/contenteditable-height-transition). It all works good, except for one thing, deleting characters, to be specific, a line, will not animate its height, unlike adding new lines. I have still a little knowledge on CSS.

```css
.autogrow {
  border: 1px solid rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
  padding: 10px;
}
@keyframes line_insert {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 20px;
  }
}
.autogrow[contenteditable] > div {
  animation-duration: 250ms;
  animation-name: line_insert;
}
.autogrow[contenteditable] {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autogrow" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it doesn't animate either, it does well though while pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Just the removing of lines and the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination while entering a new line is the problem.

How to make it work? Can it be done using pure CSS? Or adding a javascript function for it?

Comment: Can you post your code and explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Roysh
It's just the same on the links that I posted.

Comment: going through it now. Hope I'll be able to help

Comment: Any help will do as long as it works, or as long as it gives hints or ideas on how to make it work. :)

Comment: That's the closest I can get now https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/581/

Comment: The shift+key works. But when deleting lines, there are some empty lines that are not removed (due to the append function maybe). The deleting of lines doesn't animate too. Well, the idea for the shift+key works with some "fix" needed. :)

Comment: I know. I'll see if I can do something about it

Comment: I appreciate your effort mate. :)

Comment: I got it working without the deleting event... now I am trying to figure that out

Comment: @Roysh
I would appreciate it if you up vote my question, it might helps others who encounters this situation. :)

Comment: Done. I might get more ideas later.

Comment: @Roysh
Can you post your answer for the shift+enter function?

Comment: just did. look below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid these issues, I personally use a solution not based on pure CSS animations / transitions which I found always have problems. For example, in your CSS implementation, there is a bounce back effect if using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> too fast (you can slow the animation down to see it better).

[image: Bounce back effect]

Moreover, new lines handling is different between browsers, some will add `<div><br></div>`, some versions of IE add only `<br>`, etc.

I've never been able to fix all these problems or found an implementation fixing all of these so I decided to not modify at all the behavior of the `contenteditable`, let the browser do is magic which works and instead, react to what's happening.

We don't even have to worry about keys events like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or events like deletion, etc., all of these are natively handled by the navigator.

I choose instead to use 2 elements: one for the actual `contenteditable` and one for the styling of my `contenteditable` which will be the one having height animations / transitions based on the actual height of the `contenteditable`.

To do that, I'm monitoring every events that can change the height of a `contenteditable` and if the height of my *styling element* is not the same, I'm animating the *styling element*.

```js
var kAnimationSpeed = 125;
var kPadding = 10;

$('div[contenteditable]').on('blur keyup paste input', function() {
  var styleElement = $(this).prev();

  var editorHeight = $(this).height();
  var styleElementHeight = styleElement.height();

  if (editorHeight !== styleElementHeight - kPadding * 2) {
    styleElement.stop().animate({ height: editorHeight + kPadding * 2 }, kAnimationSpeed);
  }
});
```

```css
.autogrowWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.autogrow {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 40px; /* line-height + 2 * padding */
}

div[contenteditable] {
  outline: none;
  line-height : 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; /* padding */
  left: 10px; /* padding */
  right: 10px; /* padding */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="autogrowWrapper">
  <div class="autogrow"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works good. Well, I'm still an amateur, that I didn't think these kind of approach, but it works well. I will appreciate if you will up vote my question, these will help others who experienced the same situation that I encounter. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hacky, but it works.

First, modify your CSS

```
.autogrow {
  border: 1px solid rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
  padding: 10px;
}
@keyframes line_insert {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    height: 20px;
  }
}
.autogrow[contenteditable] > div {
  animation-duration: 250ms;
  animation-name: line_insert;
}
.autogrow[contenteditable] {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Then add this jQuery that detects <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  events and appends a div whenever they occur

```
$(".autogrow").keydown(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey || e.keyCode == 13)
    {
       $(this).animate({height: $(this).height()+20},200);
                $(this).append('<div><br></div>');
    }
});
```

And that should work.

Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/582/

Comment: I modify your code to test out the deleting function using line counters by counting `<br>`s. I'm using shift+enter keys for entering a new line. Maybe you can do some alteration on the code to make it work. It does work, but needs some coding. https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/609/

Comment: I was actually thinking about you've done. Give me a few hours and I'll try to fix that