# flexible height of <textarea> as a new line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I haven't seen this done before but I'm hoping it can be done. I'm trying to have an automatic height of a textarea as text is written inside of it. As seen here...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxRfj.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzYT.jpg

Hopefully these images explain what I mean. the second image is also showing its theoretical max height.

https://jsfiddle.net/nupk26Ly/

```
.text-f {
border: none;
border-bottom: #183A4C solid 1px;
color: #183A4C;
font: 1rem/2.4rem Georgia, serif;
margin-top: 40px;
resize: none;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can try this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38417557/6395838 Using `contentedible` + autogrow with height transition. It acts like a textarea or a textbox with autogrow functionality.

Comment: Why have you set resize to none then? https://davidwalsh.name/textarea-resize

Comment: Not supported by ie http://caniuse.com/#search=resize

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution using jquery. Hope it helps.

```js
function h(e) {
  $(e).css({'height':'40','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
}
$('textarea').each(function () {
  h(this);
}).on('input', function () {
  h(this);
});
```

```css
.text-f {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: #183A4C solid 1px;
    color: #183A4C;
    font: 1rem/2.4rem Georgia, serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-btn {
    background: #183A4C;
    border: solid 1px #183A4C;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font: 1rem/1.333rem Georgia, serif;
    height: 30px;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="Message" class="text-f" placeholder="Describe your project..."></textarea>

<button class="form-btn" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Pure Javascript solution (PS: I added an ID (textarea) to the textarea tag )

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = "";
  /* textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, 300) + "px"; */
textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px"
};
```

```css
.text-f {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: #183A4C solid 1px;
  color: #183A4C;
  font: 1rem/2.4rem Georgia, serif;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="main-headline">
    <h1 class="main-header">Fill out the form or contact me alternatively.</h1>
  </div>

  <!----- content ------>
  <div class="content-container">
   <!----- row 1 ------>
    <section class="row">
      <!----- form ------>
      <form name="contact-f" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="col-3 c-right-col">
          <textarea id="textarea" name="Message" class="text-f" placeholder="Describe your project..."></textarea>
          <button class="link-btn form-btn" type="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks clean and I see it works. But I can't seem to get it to work on in my project, no clue why. I may have to go with Rachel's answer. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I'm now going with your answer Jinu, it has more flexibility for alignment. However the jquery isn't working in my project but it's fine here https://jsfiddle.net/o066jcn7/2/ . Once I work it out I'll mark this as correct :) ...(solution was to insert script inside the body tag)

Comment: you can use pure javascript for this. I will give a solution using pure js. check out this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o066jcn7/3/

Comment: Cheers, I did manage to get the jquery working. Javascript / Jquery are far behond me so thanks for the help.

Comment: Why did u use Math.min? Why is that necessary?

Comment: @JonNezbit math.min can be used to set a limit to the textarea height like this textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, 100) + "px"; - here the textarea will have a height limit of 100px.  You don't need to use Math.min in this solution. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

this is a an [auto-expandable text area](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/3tmdbtd6/) that i did a while ago, might work for you. works on mobiles too

```js
$(document)
    .one('focus.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0,
            rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });

function updateTextbox(text) {
 $('#cagetextbox').val(text);
 //$('#cagetextbox').attr("rows", Math.max.apply(null, text.split("\n").map(function(a){alert(a.length);return a.length;})));
};

updateTextbox("");
```

```css
textarea{  
  display:block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  overflow:hidden;

  padding:10px;
  width:250px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:8px;
  border:6px solid #556677;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<textarea id="cagetextbox" class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Write here!! I expand!'></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: you'll note i have a min-rows specifed, likewise you can specify max-rows or max-height

Comment: Thanks a lot! works well, still need to play around with it but it seems to do the job.

Comment: great! glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document)
    .one('focus.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0,
             rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
    console.log(this.scrollHeight , this.baseScrollHeight);
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 17);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

[**Check this link**](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD)

Comment: I find that it gives this.baseScrollHeight as undefined