# Contenteditable height animation: animate only after a line is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, contenteditable

This is a continuation from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38417557/6395838).

I managed to fixed the "animation pauses every continuous keystrokes" by adding a condition `e.which === 13`, which detects and animate when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

---

This is how the previous one works:

[image]

As you can see, after entering a newline then a continues of keystrokes, the animation lags, which means the animation executes on every keystrokes.

---

These is the modified one, that will only animate after the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed:

[image]

It works smoothly (it lags a bit though during the recording).

---

These is how it works when deleting every character (not long press):

[image]

As you can see, it didn't animate well, because as you delete every character continuously, the animation pauses, just like the first attempt.

---

So what I'm trying to achieve now is the reverse one, animate smoothly after deleting a newline.

Here's a live code:

```js
var kAnimationSpeed = 250;
var kPadding = 10;

$('div[contenteditable]').on('blur keyup paste input', function(e) {
  var styleElement = $(this).prev();

  var editorHeight = $(this).height();
  var styleElementHeight = styleElement.height();

  if (editorHeight !== styleElementHeight - kPadding * 2 && e.which === 13 || e.which === 8) {
    styleElement.stop().animate({ height: editorHeight + kPadding * 2 }, kAnimationSpeed);
  }
});
```

```css
.autogrowWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.autogrow {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 40px; /* line-height + 2 * padding */
}

div[contenteditable] {
  outline: none;
  line-height : 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; /* padding */
  left: 10px; /* padding */
  right: 10px; /* padding */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="autogrowWrapper">
  <div class="autogrow"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve a smooth animation on deleting a newline, or how to animate only when a newline is deleted?

Comment: In your `if` statement, try adding something like `if ( ! $(this).is(':animated') )` as the lag *could* be multiple calls to the animation, after first calling `stop()` etc.

Comment: When I add that condition with `&&` operator, still the same. But when I tried `||` operator, it affects the enter process. Which means it works the same on the previous attempt. :v

Comment: Maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yfSUk/3/ but substitute left for top and when the value changes proceed w ur animation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347471/caret-position-in-pixels-in-an-input-type-text-not-a-textarea

Comment: @Squirrl

How to get the newline?

Comment: @Zange-chan: I've changed the event from keyup to keydown. Then at the time of 'backspace' key stroke, which is e.which === 8, I reduced the animation time. In this way we can fine tune it. Have you tried that way?

Comment: http://ichord.github.io/Caret.js/  when the top changes trigger the animation

Comment: @JTheDev

I have tried reducing the time, but I want to keep it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem based on Alex' answer.

In his answer, it only works when pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. But my goal is use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert new `<div>` inside the `contenteditable` div, while the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a new `<br>` instead of `<div>`. So I modify the code which will count `<br>`, stores the value to the data, and compares whether the current number of lines is less than the new number of lines, and also listens the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. I then replace the `e.which === 8` with `newLineDeleted` variable to tell when a new line is deleted. And remove the `input` function so it will return the exact boolean value (because it seems not to work with the `input` function in it. I add cut and paste listener as well.

[image]

```js
var kAnimationSpeed = 250;
var kPadding = 10;

$('div[contenteditable]').on('blur keyup paste', function(e) {
  var styleElement = $(this).prev();
  var editorHeight = $(this).height();
  var styleElementHeight = styleElement.height();
  
  var lineCount = parseInt($(this).data('linecount') || 0);
  var newLineCount = $(this).children('br').length;
  $(this).data('linecount', newLineCount);
  var newLineDeleted = (lineCount - 1 === newLineCount && e.which === 8);
  
  var cutPasteListener = (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 86 || e.which === 88);

  if (editorHeight !== styleElementHeight - kPadding * 2 && e.which === 13 || newLineDeleted || cutPasteListener) {
    styleElement.stop().animate({ height: editorHeight + kPadding * 2 }, kAnimationSpeed);
  }
});
```

```css
.autogrowWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.autogrow {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 40px; /* line-height + 2 * padding */
}

div[contenteditable] {
  outline: none;
  line-height : 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; /* padding */
  left: 10px; /* padding */
  right: 10px; /* padding */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="autogrowWrapper">
  <div class="autogrow"></div>
  <div contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I dont know if this works crossbrowser but Chrome adds `<div>`s for lines, so you can actually count them:

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53nn22mf/2/)

```
var kAnimationSpeed = 250;
var kPadding = 10;
var keyCodeDelete = 8;
var keyCodeReturn = 13;

$('div[contenteditable]').on('blur keyup paste', function(e) {
  var el = $(this);
  var styleElement = el.prev();
  var editorHeight = el.height();
  var styleElementHeight = styleElement.height();

  var divCount = parseInt(el.data('divcount') || 0 );
  var newDivCount = el.children('div').not(':contains("br")').length;
  var newLineDeleted = (divCount - 1 == newDivCount && e.which == keyCodeDelete);

  var heightCheck = (editorHeight !== styleElementHeight - kPadding * 2);
  var keyCodeCheck = (e.which === keyCodeReturn || e.which === keyCodeDelete);


  if (heightCheck && keyCodeCheck) {
    if (newLineDeleted) {
      $('body').append('<p>nl removed!</p>');
    }
    styleElement.stop().animate({ height: editorHeight + kPadding * 2 }, kAnimationSpeed);
  }

  el.data('divcount', newDivCount);
});
```

So you just have to adjust your animation :)

Comment: I tried your code, but still the same. But I got an idea from your code. I will make some adjustments and use some part of your code. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: I have a question. How to count the `<br>` instead of `<div>`?