# Autosize contenteditable element with smooth height transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, contenteditable

The existing questions do not cover this case. Height transition is not working when the text creates more rows. That's probably because I set no height, but I want't to keep changing it according to the text size. How can I create a smooth transition effect?

```css
.content{
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    min-height:30px; 
    width:120px;
    transition:  height 1s ease;
 }
```

```html
 <div contenteditable="true" class="content">Type more...</div>
```

Comment: Might help --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839844/contenteditable-height-transition

Comment: @ovokure, it's a bit similar and I've seen that, but it works differently (fixed heights and triggers on enter, not when typing creates new lines)