# ckeditor: Is it posible to make the editor grow horizontally as you write to a maximum of 345px?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I tried with autogrow but it only works for vertical ( I believe )
and I also tried with resize but that only works with dragging the window

```
  config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow';
  config.autoGrow_minHeight = 140;
  config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 200;
  config.autoGrow_minWidth = 190;
  config.autoGrow_maxWidth = 345;
```

Comment: Answer here looks like what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type

Comment: it doesnt work :( it is using an iframe