# Flex content sizing with input

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the shrinking of a flex container with an input inside it.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
  
  display: inline-flex;
}

input {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  min-width: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="Type something" value="foo" />
</div>
```

Can anyone explain me why the flex container thinks its content is larger than the input's size?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type) and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/) please,

Comment: You can remove to `flex: 0 0 0;` or change to `flex:1;`

Comment: actually it's considered as a bug, flex-basis is ignored, using width:0 will give you the correct output (check the bug section in the duplicate)

Answer (score -2):

Because you define a width to 0 for your input

```css
flex:0 0 0;
```

the last value to 0 is the flex-basis (it's the initial main size)

and after you define a `min-width:0` and a `width:auto` thus all is based on the 0 value

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
  
  display: inline-flex;
}

input {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="Type something" value="foo" />
</div>
```