# How do I make an input type text stretch while I'm writing in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
input {
  background-color: black;
  color: #33ff00;
  font-family: ocr a extended;
  border: 0px;
  width: 110px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

I tried display:inline-block, min-width, display:inline and they didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make html text input field grow as I type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JavaScript.

Listen for the `input` event, set the input's width to `0px` and get its `scrollWidth`, then set that back to the width of the input.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  input.style.width = "0px";
  input.style.width = input.scrollWidth + "px";
})
```

```css
input {
  background-color: black;
  color: #33ff00;
  font-family: ocr a extended;
  border: 0px;
  min-width: 110px;
  width:110px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with HTML and CSS using an editable textbox

```
<div>
   <span class="input" role="textbox" contenteditable>Type here</span>
</div>
```

Learn more: https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/

```
.input {
  background-color: black;
  color: #33ff00;
  font-family: 'ocr a extended', sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  min-width: 110px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
}
```