How to make text-input grow automatically
Code:
<input type=text autofocus />

input { /* There is only ever 1 input on this page anyways */
  max-width: 80vw;
  width: auto;
}

I want the width of my <input> to grow as the user types from an initial width of 0 to 80% of the viewport width. I want this without JS at all to ensure compatibility with older browsers, only CSS. There are two fixes I've seen online, neither of which do what I want.

Use an editable span

<span contenteditable></span>

The default span attributes make it so no CSS is required. My problem is outlined in this older example from another user asking the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168929/21973096. With contenteditable the user is able to paste html and other data, which I don't want, I want text only.

Use field-sizing

<input type=text autofocus />

input {
  field-sizing: normal;
  max-width: 80vw;
}

The field-sizing CSS property is not yet compatible with firefox and safari (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/field-sizing#browser_compatibility) and, once again, I want universal compatibility. Considering I daily drive firefox it makes this even less of an option.
Is there a way to do this without JS while ensuring compatibility and restricting input to text only?

If there was a way then the field-sizing property wouldn't have needed inventing.

Can't you past HTML into <input>? I can.

In css-tricks they have this article about auto-growing inputs:
https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/
The one i like has just a line of JS. I know you said 0 JS, but you dont have many options i think, and it's nothing to complicated.


label {
  display: inline-grid;
}

label::after {
  content: attr(data-value) ' ';
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
<label>
  <input type="text" name="" value="" oninput="this.parentNode.dataset.value = this.value" size="1">
</label>




This example uses javascript, the OP says that I don't want to use js at all

I know, I'm just pointing out another solution that should be compatible with older browsers, and, that can do what you need. Even thought I don't know how old are the browsers you want this to run.
