# how to set input width as long as the text inside

Tags: html, css

How can I set the with of `'<input>'` element equal to the content with?
(The content is dynamic.)

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WG86g/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you

`<input id="chk1" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">​`

The problem is that multiples of 8 are handled.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this. simple and easy

```
$('#textbox').autoResize();
```

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

**EDIT:**

James Padolsey left to develop this plugin. So I would recommend you to use Jack Moore's plugin. If you want to use old js file, you can access js file from here.

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js/view

https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

Comment: link doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Jack Moore's plugin serves a different purpose than what is requested

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").css("width",$(this).prop("scrollWidth"));
```