# How to tweak jQuery text-box auto-expand plugin

Tags: jquery, textbox

I found a jQuery plugin at [StackOverflow Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields/11183906#11183906) to auto-expand/contract a textbox as the user pastes/removes data from a text input. It works fine until I try to paste a substantial chunk of text into it. Then it doesn't expand at all. However it works fine if I go on typing characters, or even if I paste a small amount of text. Can anybody tell me how to tweak it to expand simultaneously even when a large chunk of data is pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the way the plugin handles the maximum width.

If a single operation (e.g. a paste) results in the element's width exceeding the maximum, the plugin does not extend the width to the maximum value, it leaves it as it is.

To work around this, I modified the code to take the maximum width into account when computing the new width:

```
// Calculate new width + whether to change
var testerWidth = testSubject.width(),
    newWidth = Math.min((testerWidth + o.comfortZone) >= minWidth
        ? testerWidth + o.comfortZone : minWidth, o.maxWidth - 1);
```

You will find an updated jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/awojer/).