# Horizontally-expanding HTML input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="TextField" />
```

and set it to resize:

```
#TextField {
   resize: horizontal;
}
```

But it does not resize.

How can I have a text field resize horizontally (not vertically) when the text nears the end (right) of the text field? Or, are there any built-in ways for this to work (maybe using something in CSS)?

Comment: What browser are you using? No versions of IE support that property.

Comment: you'll need javascript to achieve this.

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 10. I know I can achieve this with JavaScript, @rudeovskizebear - but my question is, how?

Comment: Chrome, Version 24.0.1312.57 m does not support resize: horizontal either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to calculate the width of the box based on the width of the text. Here is a simalar question that might help. [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

BTW there's a plugin which can help you achieve what you are looking for [Resize INput box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields)