# auto set size of textbox on page load to its contents

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a ton of text boxes in and rather than set the size for each text box manually, I was hoping I could set the size to the contents of the text boxes on page load.

I have found a good auto grow script here
[Is there a jQuery autogrow plugin for text fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields)

but do not know how to make them default smaller if theres say only 1 character in the textbox

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with

```
$("input").each(function(){
    var myLength = $(this).val().length;
    if(myLength == 1){
        $(this).attr('size', myLength);
        $(this).attr('class', 'mini');
    }else{
        $(this).attr('size', myLength);    
    }

});
```

and a css class:

```
.mini{
    width:10px;
}
```

Example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NA9w/3/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: this gives me error SCRIPT380: Invalid property value. 
jquery-1.8.2.min.js, line 2 character 32075
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.

Comment: it's a problem with your jquery version; in jsfiddle I used the 1.9.1. Your version it's the 1.8.2 :)

Comment: Remember to download always the last version of jQuery.. I didn't used the last one.. but seems it works on 1.9.1

Comment: looks like the problem is with another jquery pluggin you may have in the page. Try to isolate the scripts until you found the trouble.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try following thing, what if we say after some characters limit will replace input field to textarea, see following code:

```
$(".input_text").each(function(index, obj){
    var txt = $(this), txtLength = txt.val().length;
    if(txtLength <= 1){
        txt.height("25px");
    }else{
        var txtarea = $("<textarea/>");
        txt.replaceWith(txtarea.val(txt.val()));
    }
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tFDNx/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of them this all works fine

1) `<input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">`

2) `var inputEl = document.getElementById("theInput");`

```
  function getWidthOfInput() {
    var tmp = document.createElement("span");
    tmp.className = "input-element tmp-element";
    tmp.innerHTML = inputEl.value.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
    document.body.appendChild(tmp);
    var theWidth = tmp.scrollWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(tmp);
    return theWidth;
  }

  function adjustWidthOfInput() {
    inputEl.style.width = getWidthOfInput() + "px";
  }

  adjustWidthOfInput();
  inputEl.onkeyup = adjustWidthOfInput;
```

3) // HTML

// jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#input').keyup(function(){
    $('<span id="width">').append( $(this).val() ).appendTo('body');
    $(this).width( $('#width').width() + 2 );
    $('#width').remove();
  });
});
```