# auto-resizing text input box html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an input (type text) box and made it auto-resize quite simply. However, there are a few glitches that I can't seem to fix:

1. when I start typing the box shrinks a tiny bit
2. when I press backspace (or directional arrows), the box expands first, and then shrinks when I continue typing.

Here is my code:

```js
function Expander() {
     
    this.start = function () {
       
        $("#inputbox").keydown(function(e) {
                  
            this.style.width = 0;
            var newWidth = this.scrollWidth + 10;
       
            if( this.scrollWidth >= this.clientWidth )
                newWidth += 10;
        
            this.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
       
        });
      
    }
     
}
    
    
$(function() {
    window.app = new Expander();
    window.app.start();
});
```

```css
input {
     margin-left:3em;
     min-width:100px;
     max-width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>

    <div id="wrap">
     <input type="text" id="inputbox" name="input" placeholder="I want this to resize smoothly." width="100px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="counter"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: just an observation, think about when pasting text or pressing a key down and holding it. Maybe you should look at the plugin on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields instead.

Comment: thanks, i wasn't finished with my code, just wondered why it had issues. i will never learn the language if i just take the code from others :)

Comment: you don't need to just take the code, you can analyse what their code is doing so you can write your own plugin, I find that very helpful when learning.

Comment: Regarding your first question I think it shrinks because the default width of an input is 117px (at least in chrome). If you set the width in the CSS to be the same as min-width it should be fine.

Comment: Regarding your second question use the "oninput" event instead of "onkeydown".

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

We put the content in a hidden `span` & then adjust width according to `span` scrollWidth.

```js
function Expander() {

    this.start = function () {

        $('#inputbox').on('keydown',function(e) {

            $("#hidden_span").html("");
            $("#hidden_span").append("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>");

            var hidden_span_scroll_width=$("#hidden_span")[0].scrollWidth;

            if(hidden_span_scroll_width> 100||hidden_span_scroll_width< 600){
                $(this).css("width",hidden_span_scroll_width);
            }

        });

    }

}


$(function() {
    window.app = new Expander();
    window.app.start();
});
```

```css
input {
    margin-left:3em;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:600px;
}

#hidden_span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:10px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" name="input" placeholder="I want this to resize smoothly." />
</div>
<div id="counter"></div>
<span id="hidden_span"></span>
</body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
input {
    margin-left:3em;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:600px;
}
        #hidden_span{
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            visibility:hidden;
            width:10px;
            white-space:nowrap;
            overflow:hidden;

        }
</style>
<script>

function Expander() {

    this.start = function () {

        $('#inputbox').on('keydown',function(e) {


            $("#hidden_span").html("");
            $("#hidden_span").append("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>");


            var hidden_span_scroll_width=$("#hidden_span")[0].scrollWidth;

     if(hidden_span_scroll_width> 100||hidden_span_scroll_width< 600){
                $(this).css("width",hidden_span_scroll_width);
                     }


        });

    }

}


$(function() {
    window.app = new Expander();
    window.app.start();
});

</script>
<div id="wrap">
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" name="input" placeholder="yes" />
</div>
<div id="counter"></div>
<span id="hidden_span"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, this solves my issues but it doesn't resize back on delete and backspace. that's an easier fix though.

Comment: @rockerist i have edited my above code & now it should work with delete also. Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vdv9q/

Answer (score 0):

At first you can use jQuery methods to avoid crossbrowser problem. And scrollWidth returns either the width in pixels of the content of an element or the width of the element itself, whichever is greater. So enlarge newWidth only when content width strongly larger than element width.

```
$("#inputbox").keydown(function(e) {

  var a = $(this).width(), newWidth;


  if(this.scrollWidth - a > 0){
    newWidth = a + 10;
  }else if(e.keyCode==8){
    newWidth = a - 10;
  }
  $(this).css("width", newWidth);

});
```

If you don't want to make input smaller when pressed backspace - delete else if part of code.

Comment: ok, this works just fine but i kind of don't want to hardcode keys into it because this code does not work if i press delete. i wanted the box to resize solely based on its contents.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="inputbox" name="input" placeholder="yes" width="100px"/>
```

Remove the `width="100px"`, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputbox" name="input" placeholder="yes"/>
```

And it won't resize down anymore when starting to type.

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2EMfd/

Though, the exanding function doesn't seem to work in my browser?

*Edit, did a simple expand function on the `inputbox` is this what you where trying? http://jsfiddle.net/2EMfd/1/

Comment: thanks, but no. the second link resizes on every key press, even on cmd and directional arrows. i need it to expand as the contents inside it reach near the width of the input box.