# Smart resizing for rows of html inputs

Tags: css

I have a `tr` with `td`'s containing `input`s. I'm not applying any `size` attribute or `style` with regard to `width`.

Some `input`s contain just single digits and some contain words. The ones containing single digits have much extra white space and the ones containing words contain far less.

When I resize the page containing the `table`, the `table` shrinks to keep fitting 100% of the page. But, all the `input`s seem to basically resize at about the same rate with no regard for which `input` has the most space to give up. By space, I mean the empty area in the `input` that does not show any data; the extra space to the right (as my inputs are left aligned).

[image: <code>input</code>s are not reduced intelligently]

Is there a css property that would apply to this situation to help accomplish reducing the `size` of the `input`s which have the most white space to give up first and putting off truncating visible text as long as possible?

Comment: You should use percent width for each column here and + set min-width for some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try auto sizing the inputs using a script like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/931695/288568

Anyways, the script is not for drop downs so far, but could be adapted.

But: If in the first line there is a 1 and in the second a 11 then the inputs would have different sizes.

Comment: http://samtag.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/js/jquery.autoGrowInput.js is no longer a valid url :)

Comment: I did not mention that URL?

Comment: I looked at it again, and unless I'm misunderstanding, this script is to resize a single textbox for key events according to the content of the textbox, not resize sets of textboxes a certain way when their container (in my case the `TABLE`) resizes. Technically, I would be resizing `TD` elements based on all `INPUT`s in that column, then just resizing the `INPUT` elements to fill the calculated size. Does that make sense?