# how to make a html input expand when the text inside is larger then the input itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-input

I have a input (html element) and sometimes the input (text) from the user is larger then the width of the input (html element) is there a way to make the input (html element) auto grow when the user is typing?

Obs. Better if made only with css

-------------------------------------EDIT 1-----------------------------------

I've made a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Supitto/2rpctygh/1/), and as you can see the text is cropped when you enter to much text. I'm now trying to make it work with `<span contenteditable="true" >`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168727/make-html-text-input-field-grow-as-i-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a no javascript/jquery solution I would recommend you to use `contenteditable` div instead of input element

Here's an example
https://jsfiddle.net/sohelansari/631uzco9

Or if you want to use input element only, then unfortunately a pure css solution is not possible.
You can write a jquery plugin, may be something like this -> [Is there a jQuery autogrow plugin for text fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931207/is-there-a-jquery-autogrow-plugin-for-text-fields).

Comment: Is there a way to remove the bounding box that appears when you click on the span?

Comment: @HenriqueAlmeidaMarcomini yes you can. I have updated the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Your method worked like a charm. Althrough I belive css is supposed to handle that. Got my vote and the right answer

Comment: there's any way to add a placeholder on this approach ? @shinobi

Comment: @FelipeQuirós There is no direct way to do that unfortunately. You will have to use a bit of work around with a placeholder div and some javascript to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span contenteditable="true" style="display: inline-block; border: solid 1px black; min-width: 50px; max-width: 200px"></span>
```

Comment: Hi bootle; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `oninput="this.size = this.value.length"` to your input tag.

```html
<input
  type="text"
  oninput="this.size = this.value.length"
/>
```

Comment: But how does it skips to the next line? after adding an specific width, this doesnt seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    function copy_data(val){
     var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
     document.getElementById("text_to").value=a
    }    
</script>
</head>
<TEXTAREA ID="text_from" style="height:100px; width:600px;">

</TEXTAREA>

<TEXTAREA ID="text_to" style="height:100px; width:600px;">

</TEXTAREA>
<button onclick=copy_data(text_from)>Copy</button>
```